# fadein heading while the buttons remains constant in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, removeclass

I'm very much basic to jquery so im doing a site where when the page loads, i want my Heading on the top jumbotron fadeIn while the buttons below remains constant.
Could someone help me with this.because the buttons stay on top when the page starts and comes back to its position, i mean to the bottom. when the page completely loads and the Heading fadein...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main-heading').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('main-heading-hidden');
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url("googlenownewyork.png");
 background-position: center center ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height: 600px;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main-heading{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top:140px;
}

.main-heading-hidden{
display: none;
} 

.header-button{
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 30px;
}

.header-button .btn:hover{
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script src="metcorp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container first-div">
   <div class="row main-heading main-heading-hidden">
   
    <h1>Mount Edge Technologies</h1>
    <h3></h3>
   </div>
   <div class="row header-button btn-padding">
    <button type="button" class="btn">About Us</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Get A Quote</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: none` removes the header from the layout of the page.

Rather than display, try opacity.

You can also do this with css3 animations fairly easily, avoiding needing to use jquery's fadeIn function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ff0h95aw/)

**Add this script link to your code.**

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And Don't write this code in ready function:
write directly in script

```
$('.main-heading').fadeIn(2000).removeClass('main-heading-hidden');
```